# Check_box_tag RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my check_box_tag in form is
`<div class= 'col-md-9 form-group'><%=check_box_tag :Stock_permission, "1" %></div>`

where the Stock_permission is the string. but when i click submit button the parameter is passed but it didn't save it in Database

Parameter

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Li3Gf1L/lsMI6LPfGHlfL2TOaDaO9u85FlEmYNgC9YI=", "user_authentication"=>{"name"=>"Ebenezer Raja", "email"=>"ebenezer.raja1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "permission_type"=>"admin", "login_allowed"=>"1"}, "selected_homes"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], **"Stock_permission"=>"1"**, "Attention_permission"=>"1", "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your [`check_box`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) helper outside of the `user_authentication` params.

I assume you are use a form_for helper and something like this should fix your problem:

```
<%= form_for :some, url: some_path do |f| %>
 # some code here
  <div class= 'col-md-9 form-group'>
    <%= f.check_box :Stock_permission, "1" %>
  </div>
 # some code here
```

Comment: It works, but new error raises now in browser it says "undefined method `merge' for "Stock":String".

Comment: it's something hidden from me. :)